# admob banner ads overlaps main layout

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

Admob banner ads in my android app overlaps bottom of the main layout, there are many solutions on here but non of them is working for me.how do i separate this two layouts. following is my activity.main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemIconTint="#d20b0d"
        app:itemTextColor="#333"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_items" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem is that**:

Admob Ad is align on TOP|BOTTOM wrt Parent, hence its overlapping your WebView which is acquiring Full width and Height of screen.

There is two way which you can follow to avoid overlapping of Ads on WebView

**Solution 1**:

Give margin_bottom to Webview

```
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"  or android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
```

As you are using "**SMART BANNER**" you can configure hardcode value i.e "50dp" and "90dp" in two different "**dimens.xml**" wrt Screen Resolution and Size

**Solution 2**:

You can use LinearLayout to contain both "WebView" and "Admob Ad" and assign weight to webview only, like below code.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminate="false"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemIconTint="#d20b0d"
        app:itemTextColor="#333"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_items"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Choice is yours you which you follow.

**Note**: Don't use **fill_parent** in your layouts as they are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="false" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"

            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:itemIconTint="#d20b0d"
    app:itemTextColor="#333"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_items" />
```

Comment: give some hardcode height to adview .. check code again i will update the code

Comment: I also need help regarding, I placed banner at top of screen but when ever drawer navigation view open it cover banner half horizontally. today I got mail about fix this issue as soon as possible but I really have no Idea about content overlap cause from this or any other native or banner. please correct me here can drawer cause overlapping ads issue ??? Need Help